# Finding all rows of 2 variables using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose I have a system of linear equations. Using Gaussian elimination, I can determine whether a solution exists, and even find a valid solution.

During the elimination, I can combine rows together, to produce new rows with different number of variables. Is there a method to find all possible rows that contain exactly 2 variables? For example, I may want to find all equalities between variables. This is equivalent to finding all rows that contain exactly 2 variables. Is it possible to do this without trying all (exponentially many) combinations of rows?

For example if I have:

Row 1: A xor B xor C = 1

Row 2: A xor B xor D = 1

I can combine row 1 and row 2 to say that C xor D = 0

If I have a large amount of rows, and they require large combinations of large rows to produce smaller rows, is it trivial or hard to find all rows of size 2? Can I do better than adding random pairs to the system and checking it still has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a matrix $M$ over $GF(2)$ (the field with two elements), and want to find all linear combinations of rows which have weight exactly $2$.

Using Gaussian elimination, you can bring your matrix into [echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). This makes it easy to determine, for any particular row, whether it is in the span of the rows of $M$. Since there are only $\binom{n}{2}$ many rows of weight $2$, the entire algorithm will run in polynomial time. (It is likely that this can be optimized further.)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Once I have echelon form, what does it mean to check if a row is in the span of the rows of the matrix?

Comment: This is basic linear algebra terminology. Pick up any textbook or lecture notes.

Comment: The span of a set of vectors (in this case, rows) consists of all linear combinations of the vectors.

Comment: Okay, so for each of the $\binom{n}{2}$  possible rows, I can check whether it is a linear combination of the rows of matrix, in echelon form. This gives me quadratic complexity. If I wanted rows of size 3, it would scale up to cubic complexity. For larger rows, it would be quickly infeasible. When you say it is likely that this can be optimized further, do you believe there could be a way to directly find the true rows? The number of possible rows of any size is 2^n, so this looks as hard as resolution proof.

Comment: You’re changing the question. Seems like you want to ask a new one.

Comment: One more thing about this question, if you are still here. You say once I have echelon form, it is easy for any desired row, to check whether it is in the span of the rows of the matrix. According to the solutions I find for this, I have to do elimination on a new matrix every time for each candidate row. Basically I have to solve a new linear system every time, to check if the row is a linear combination. Is there a quicker way? Otherwise complexity becomes cubic for rows of weight 2 already.

Comment: Yes. Once the matrix is in echelon form, it's easy to check whether a given vector is in the row span. I'll let you work it out.

Comment: I've been thinking for hours, I still can't work out how easy it is exactly. I opened a separate question in case you want to enlighten me.
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125287/check-if-a-row-is-in-the-span-of-a-matrix