# Check if a row is in the span of a matrix

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose I have a matrix $M$ over $GF(2)$ with rows that represent a system of linear equations:

A xor B xor C = 1

A xor B xor D = 1

X xor A xor Z = 0

etc...

For a new external row, I want the ability to tell if it is a linear combination of the rows of the matrix, or not. I could do this by computing the augmented matrix, and solving it with Gaussian Elimination.

For example I want to know if this is true or not:

X xor B = 1

Now, suppose I have a lot of rows to test (8 billions). I do not wish to recompute a new augmented matrix each time. I heard there is a way to compute the echelon form once and use it to determine whether a given row is in the span of the matrix or not, but I cannot figure out how.

How easy is it to determine whether a given row is in the span of a matrix in echelon form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your vector be $x$, and let the first row be $r$.

If $x_1 = 1$ and $r_1 = 0$, then $x$ is not in the span.

If $x_1 = 0$ and $r_1 = 1$, then $r$ cannot be part in any linear combination that results in $x$, so we can remove $r$ and continue.

If $x_1 = 0$ and $r_1 = 0$, then we can remove the first column and continue.

If $x_1 = 1$ and $r_1 = 1$, then for $x$ to be a linear combination of the rows, $r$ must be one of the rows in the linear combination. So we can replace $x$ with $x \oplus r$, remove the first row and column, and continue.

---

You can also present this algorithm in an iterative manner.

Let $i$ be the index of the first $1$ in $x$. For $x$ to be in the span, there must be a row whose first $1$ is also at index $i$. Find this row $r$, replace $x$ with $x \oplus r$, and continue, until eventually $x = 0$.

Comment: Interestingly simple. Do I need the reduced echelon form for this algorithm to be valid?

Comment: I’ll let you figure that out. Try to understand why this algorithm is working.

Comment: "For x to be in the span, there must be a row whose first 1 is also at index i."
I'm unable to see why this assumption would be true in the non reduced case. In the reduced case it would be logical since it would be the only row with a 1 at index i.

Comment: Excellent - do you got your answer.